# Magento ver. 1.4.1.1 outof stock item display

Tags: php, magento

I am using Magento ver. 1.4.1.1 and its working fine.

But when I put any item out of stock, it disappears from the website.

I need that product to stay on website, but display "out-of-stock" so people can't buy that item anymore.

I've been searching for a solution all day, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System->Configuration, then in left menu CATALOG->Inventory->Stock Options, Display Out of Stock Products set to Yes.